# Simultaneous X&Y axis scroll not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

The following code behaves as i want in chrome, opera and safari but not in firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/coolcatDev/m2uehfzx/9/

I have a table that overflows on x-axis. I wish the x-scrollbar to be attached to the table not the body.

I want the title to stay fixed on x-scroll of the table.

I cant find the right settings for css overflow on the different containers in order to allow Simultaneous X&Y axis scroll on all browsers.

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="superResponsive">
                          <tr>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>    
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>    
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>    
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>    
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>    
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>      
                            <td>50</td>
                          </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</body>
```

css:

```
body{
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.container{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.table-responsive{
    overflow-x: auto;

}

.superResponsive{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #0887A7!important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%!important;
}

.superResponsive td{
    border: 1px solid lightBlue;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This is best noticed using trackpad or mouses with digital scroll sensor, any ideas on what is heppening

Comment: For some reason with the current shown css settings in order to transit from x to y scroll, or other way around, it is required to move the mouse at least 1 px